# How do I get the objects from a list of objects which contain a duplicate property inside of another list in the object?

Tags: c#, list, linq, duplicates

I've got the following object example:

```
public class Event
{
...
    public NextEventStatus NextStatus { get; set; }
...
}

public class NextEventStatus 
{
    public List<Person> People{ get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

If I have e.g. `List<Event>` containing 3 `Event` objects, in each of them there is `NextStatus` property containing a  `People` property of type `List<Person>` with just 1 entry, such as e.g.:

```
//In Event object 1
Name = "person1"
Email = "person1email@anemail.com"

//In Event object 2
Name = "person2"
Email = "person2email@anemail.com"

//In Event object 3
Name = "person1"
Email = "person1email@anemail.com"
```

Is it all possible to get the only the `Event` objects which contain the same `Email` property inside of the `List<Person>` , so for an object containing the above, it would return the full Event objects 1 and 3 but not Event object 2? So it is looking for duplicates in a list inside of a list.

I've looked at how this can be done but a bit lost in how you do a GroupBy when you need to access another list, since the initial object will be a `List<Event>`, and then there is a property `People` which is a `List<Person>` which is the one where looking for duplicates in

```
var originalEventList = new List<Event>();
//Add objects to list here...

var eventListWithDuplicates = originalEventList.GroupBy(x => x.NextStatus.People) ...
```

Comment: What if event1 and event 3 had 2 people each? Are the people always in the same order? Does order matter? Do you essentially want "a list of all events that are attended by the same crowd of people" ?

Comment: Do you mean if e.g. event1 and event3 both had an additional person, but that additional person wasn't the same person, so there would only be 1 common duplicate person between the two? From the list of events, I basically need all the event objects in which there is a duplicate/the property is the same inside of that ``List<Person>``, so if e.g. just looking at the Name property of Person, all the Event objects where the same Name property appears more than once

Comment: What if e1 had p1 & p2, and e2 had p2 & p3, and e3 had p1, then e1 & e2 share p2 and e1 & e3 share p3, what answer do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the following:

```cs
var grouped =
    from e in originalEventList
    from p in e.NextStatus.Persons
    group e by p.Email into g
    where g.Count() > 1
    select g;

var result = grouped.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with LINQ, but I'm not sure it'll be easier to understand than a non-LINQ version

```
var em = new Dictionary<string, Event>();
var ev = new HashSet<Event>();

foreach(var e in eventList)
  foreach(var p in e.NextStatus.People)
    if(!em.TryAdd(p.Email, e)){
       ev.Add(e);
       ev.Add(em[p.Email]);
    }
```

`ev` now contains a set of events attended by only people who are extra sociable :). So how does it work? We enumerate all the events and all the people, trying to add every email address to a Dictionary together with that particular Event being attended. If the attempt to add the email to the dictionary returns `false` it means "the dictionary already contains that email". Because we've seen the email before it means the current person is on at least one other event so both this event `e` and  *that* event from the dictionary `d[p.Email]` should be added to the set. A HashSet doesn't allow duplicates so if an event has been seen before it won't be added. Note that the email will be treated case sensitively, and "bill@microsoft.com" is not "Bill@microsoft.com"

I suppose a LINQ approach might look like

```
eventList
  .SelectMany(e => e.NextStatus.People, (E, P) => new { E, P })
  .GroupBy(ep => ep.P.Email)
  .Where(g => g.Count > 1)
  .SelectMany(g => g.E)
  .Distinct()
```

Here it unpacks the eventList to an anonymous type that has a single event/person pair, groups them by person email, filters them to only those groups that contain more than one event, unpacks the list-of-list-of-Event to a single list of event and then discards duplicated events using distinct. It's massively less efficient than the first approach